# Is it possible to access the results of **previously** run command in Bash?

Tags: linux, command-line, bash

Often I found that I've run a command in bash and realize after running it that I'd like to grep (or otherwise) access the result. I want to **avoid rerunning the command** either because of the run time or because it uses a resource that won't give the same output. Is there one or more ways to do this?

Comment: This can't be done after the command has been run.

Comment: I know how to do redirects. My point is that I want to access the results of a command AFTER it's already been run (but still in the terminal buffer)

Comment: Make `tmux` your everyday tool, then read this: [*Write all `tmux` scrollback to a file*](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/26548/108618).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way for scripts is to declare text variable and save command output in it.
Then you may use this var as many times as you want.

```
Out=$(command)

echo "$Out" | grep 'some text'
echo "$Out" | grep 'other text'

unset Out      #or just logout
```

The other way is to save output to text file, but you need to have write permissions on disk and remove file after using.

Also there are some other ways to access terminal log:

1. Setup terminal logging of OS to remote server via `auditd` and `pam_tty_audit.so`. Log will be stored on remote Log server. Only User input saved and user could not modify it.
2. Setup logging to file in user terminal (Putty, SecureCRT have session options about it). Log is stored on user machine
3. Get session logging via `rootsh`.

Comment: My point is that I want to access the results of a command AFTER it's already been run (but still in the terminal buffer).

Answer (score 0):

You could use commands like tee and xargs

```
tee - read from standard input and write to standard output and files 
xargs - build and execute command lines from standard input
```

to redirect the output into a file from where you can access it

Comment: My point is that I want to access the results of a command AFTER it's already been run (but still in the terminal buffer), so redirects aren't an option here.